how to build a high-performance upload service with formidable and NextRequest
In fact, there were a lot of implemented with api-routes, it's easy and user-friendly. But when using with NextRequest, it would be very confusing and difficult. Because the NextRequest is using the Web standard Request instead of the IncomingMessage in NextApiRequest.
formidable.parse can not accept NextRequest directly, even if converted in other ways...
const req: NextRequest = ...;

// error on this: req.on is not a function
formidable.parse(req);

// error on this too: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content-length')
const formData = await req.formData();
const file = formData.get('file') as File;
const fileStream = Readable.fromWeb(file.stream(), { encoding: 'utf-8' });
const [fields, files] = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    formidable.parse(fileStream, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            reject(null);
        }
        resolve({ fields, files });
    });
});

I have searched and asked some AI tools, but they still do not work for me!
I found there was no option for Route Handlers that set a bodyParser, the official said that Notably, unlike API Routes with the Pages Router, you do not need to use bodyParser to use any additional configuration.
So, Is it really no way to use formidable and NextRequest(Route Handlers) together?
Or, making a perfect mapping for NextRequest to IncomingMessage?

Did you end up with a solution at all? Same boat here
